# Call handling on Android

Tags: android

I came across this problem several times in google group Android, here on SO and other communication platform. I'm aiming for the functionalities of the internal interface com.android.internal.telephony.Phone

Right now I managed to answer a call programmatically and also answer the second call (and thus put first call on hold) via TelephonyManager's `getITelephony()` and Reflection for `answerRingingCall()/endCall()`

Now I'm trying to access the function `conference() throws CallStateException` from the Phone interface mentioned above.

Therefore I've created a package with the class Phone.aidl

```
package com.android.internal.telephony;

interface Phone {

void conference();
void switchHoldingAndActive();
}
```

This class generates the Phone interface with the 2 functions in the /gen/ folder.
Now I created a class to extend this Stub

```
import android.os.RemoteException;
import com.android.internal.telephony.Phone;
public class Gdata extends Phone.Stub {
public void conference() throws RemoteException {}
public void switchHoldingAndActive() throws RemoteException {}
}
```

If i try to run this in my activity it looks like this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
try {
Gdata gd = new Gdata();
                gd.conference();
                Log.i("Conference", "working....");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("Conference", "not working....");
            }}
    });
```

Now to my output on LogCat, what actually makes this case interesting:
First when loading my Gdata class

```
01-25 15:30:31.023: D/dalvikvm(5993): Note: class     Lcom/android/internal/telephony/Phone$Stub; has 295 unimplemented (abstract) methods
```

Then right after it, after my two functions are declared in the Gdata class

```
01-25 15:30:31.023: D/dalvikvm(5993): Note: class Lcom/android/internal/telephony/Phone$Stub$Proxy; has 293 unimplemented (abstract) methods
```

This is actually indicating that I caught the right class with my Phone.aidl and also the right methods/functions. For example: If I implement in my Phone.aidl a random void called fun() then the dalvikvm gives me an error and quits the application immediately - so this proves also that the methods in my Phone.aidl were assigned correctly to the internal interface-methods.

I don't neither errors nor warnings but something seems to be missing because it actually doesn't do the conference() function while having one calls on hold and one active call.

I've also implemented the method switchHoldingAndActive(), this one also doesn't give me any error/warning but it also doesn't work.

I've been working on that issue for a couple of weeks now and my actual state makes me feel like I'm quite near the answer. Could anybody help me out with that?

Comment: Have you found any leads on this issue so far?